# Filter on Category and Postformat

Tags: wordpress, categories, post-format

I have just started in Wordpress Template development, I am getting used to it.

However I have been looking to find the solution here but unable to find the same question.

I would like to filter on Category and Post-Format, i have the following code the Filter on the Post Format works however not on the Category.

```
$videos = new WP_Query( array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(                
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 
        'post-format-video'
        ),
        'category_name=instructie-videos',
        'posts_per_page=6',
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
)
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $videos = new WP_Query( array(
 'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
 'posts_per_page' => 6,
 'category_name' => 'instructie-videos',
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(                
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array( 'post-format-video' ),
          'operator' => 'IN'
      )
    )
 ) );
```

maybe it's syntax mistake near `category_name`. Try above code

Comment: Dear Parthavi, Many thanks for your repsonse i will try this

Comment: Hi, this also does not seem to work, i changed the post type to post and also tried without post type

Comment: remove `'operator' => 'IN'` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you should try as below:

```js
$myposts = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 
                'post-format-aside',
                'post-format-audio',
                'post-format-chat',
                'post-format-gallery',
                'post-format-image',
                'post-format-link',
                'post-format-quote',
                'post-format-status',
                'post-format-video'
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
) );
```

Comment: Hi this does not include the Category